# gitolite: default remotes for new repository

Tags: git, gitolite

I've installed gitolite (locally for now, to experiment) and it seems to work, except that new repositories are not tracking the remote by default after a git clone. If I remember correctly, when I clone a repository from github.com, it's already able to push and pull.

Here is what I tried:

```
$ git clone git@localhost:sandbox
Cloning into sandbox...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
$ echo "A" > README
$ git add README
$ git commit README -m 'test'
$ git push
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@localhost:sandbox'
```

When I try to push explicitly everything works:

```
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 426 bytes, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@localhost:sandbox
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Is this additional step really needed? Can be set by default? On github it is, isn't?

Thank you

Comment: As I understand, gitosis is not recommended anymore for new repositories/servers. Better use gitolite.

Comment: Oops, I'm actually using gitolite, but made a mistake in the question. Now is fixed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The first git push always require to specify the branch you want to push.

```
git push -u origin master
```

Then the next push can be done, from the same branch, as you intended:

```
git push
```

From [`git push` man page](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html):

> The special refspec `:` (or `+:` to allow non-fast-forward updates) directs git to push "matching" branches: for every branch that exists on the local side, the remote side is updated if a branch of the same name already exists on the remote side.
>   **This is the default operation mode if no explicit refspec is found**.

Since you have cloned an empty repository, the first push doesn't find any matching branch (there is none on the upstream repo '`origin`')

Note: See "[What is the result of `git push origin`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586687/what-is-the-result-of-git-push-origin/9749477#9749477)":

The default policy for git push will change with git 2.0 (or maybe git1.9)

> A new mode for push, "**`simple`**", which is a cross between "`current`" and "`upstream`", has been introduced.
>   "`git push`" without any refspec will **push the current branch out to the same name at the remote repository only when it is set to track the branch with the same name over there**.
>   The plan is to make this mode the new default value when `push.default` is not configured.

So in the `git push -u origin master`, the `-u` (`--set-upstream-to`) is important here (not just to push the branch with the same name to the remote '`origin`', but it a remote tracking branch.

Comment: Thank you, so for the meantime I'll get used to it. So probably github initializes the repo for you. I'll check with a dummy repo at the first occasion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git branch --set-upstream` command, eg.:
 `git branch --set-upstream develop origin/develop`