# git push vs git push origin <branchname>

Tags: git

I'm quite new to Git.

I'm creating a branch and then want to push it to `origin`.

I think that simply issuing `git push` (while standing on my branch) should be sufficient.

Is it possible/reasonable to do that (by specifying push.default simple)?

Comment: yes offcourse, you should be able to do git push without saying git push -u origin master. 

u is for setting the upstream, you should do the git push - u origin <branch name> to set the upstream at least for once, and then you can do git push just like that

Comment: also check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/git-push-current-branch?rq=1 to set the push.default if you need to

Answer (score 60):

The first push should be a:

```
git push -u origin branchname
```

That would make sure:

- your local branch has a [remote tracking branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4697054/6309) of the same name referring an [upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309) in your remote repo '`origin`',
- this is compliant with the [default push policy '`simple`'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6547682/6309)

Any future git push will, with that default policy, only push the current branch, and only if that branch has an upstream branch with the same name.
that avoid pushing *all* matching branches (previous default policy), where tons of test branches were pushed even though they aren't ready to be visible on the [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309).

Comment: Am I right at understanding that I should do two things: 1) issue `git push -u origin branchname` on first branch push 2) set push.default simple ?

Comment: Actually I thought that git automatically links current local branch with remote branch created by issuing `git push origin branchname`. This would be reasonable for it to do so. I mean, it's kind of strange that I need to explicitly specify that local branch I'm pushing to origin should be linked with local branch I'm pushing from.

Comment: `git push origin branchname` **does not link local and upstream branch**. You need to make that link explicit with -u. Again: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309

Answer (score 33):

First, you need to create your branch locally

```
git checkout -b your_branch
```

After that, you can work locally in your branch, when you are ready to share the branch, push it. The next command push the branch to the remote repository origin and tracks it

```
git push -u origin your_branch
```

Your Teammates/colleagues can push to your branch by doing commits and then push explicitly

```
... work ...
git commit
... work ...
git commit
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/your_branch
```

Answer (score 1):

The commands `git pull` and `git push` are used to move commits between a local and a remote repository. But under the hood, the local branch is totally different/separated from the remote one. What happens in `push` and `pull` is kind of a merge between both of them with a fast forward condition if possible.

We usually try to keep local and remote in sync with each other, so it's normal to give the same name to a branch in local and in remote, but this is not required. You could have a local branch `feature_A` being represented by a remote one `any_other_name` with no problem.

So if you put it together, we have different branches not being tied by name, which makes it possible for you to `pull` and `push` (*merging*) any remote branch to any local branch. That is why only a git push doesn't work. Because you could push it to any of the existing branches on remote and git doesn't know what you mean.

But we clearly do `pull` and `push` more often to sync between local and remote. So for the first time you pushing a new local branch, with the intention to create a corresponding branch with the same name into remote, you have to use the `set-upstream` option on command to tie each other. After this, a simple `git push` will do the job to sync, but it would be still possible to `push` (*merging*) it to another remote branch, but in this case, you should use the full command.

**NOTE:** Just be aware of the side effects you can have using just `git push` if your git has more than one remote configured