# Some git environments require "origin <branch>" for push, others don't. Why?

Tags: git

On my iMac, I can do `git push` and it works fine.  But on my Macbook, I have to use `git push origin <branchname>`.  The .git/config files on the two are the same, repo is the same - what's the difference?

Comment: What versions of Git are installed on the two machines?  What upstream, if any, is set for the current branch in each case?  (I'm assuming you are not doing either push from "detached HEAD" mode.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a change in the **push.default** config value: It used to be: `matching` and now it is `simple` this may cause the difference. You can set this config value as desire, see: [git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for explanation on those values (and more values available).

Comment: That was it. On the Macbook the default was `matching`, but on my iMac it was `current.`  I like current so I used `git config --global push.default current` on the Macbook to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Normally only the first push of a new local branch should require `git push -u origin branchname` to set a remote tracking branch to your local one. The following pushes should work with `git push` because Git already knows what the remote of this local branch is.

See also: [git push vs git push origin <branchname>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312622/git-push-vs-git-push-origin-branchname)