# Specify the 'origin/master' part in a git push

Tags: git, push, git-branch, remote-branch

If I do a git push, I see 3 branches involved. 1) The local branch I am working on, say 'foo1' 2) the local remote-tracking branch 'origin/foo2' (which always is on the same commit as the remote foo3 after push/pull) 3) 'foo3' in the remote repo. Naturally normally they all would be called foo, but I want different names so I can properly understand git and ask this question here. I don't understand where I can specify foo2. When I do

```
git push origin foo1:foo3
```

And having that in my .git/config

```
[branch "master"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/remotes/origin/foo2
```

Point 1 and 3 are ok, but I don't have an origin/foo2 in my local repo. What am I missing? Or is the answer that my remote tracking branches are *always* named exactly the same way as the remotes - that would be fine for me - I just want to understand git properly.

The git-push manual also only talks about two refs (the refspec src and dst), point 1 and 3, in my example. Where does the manual talk about that after the dst branch on the remote repo is updated, also the local remote-tracking ref is updated?

Comment: @VonC's answer is correct (of course :-) ).  I suspect the fundamental problem here is that you're tripping up over the apparent symmetry between `push` and `pull`.  It's a false symmetry.  The opposite of `push` is not `pull`, it's `fetch`.  (Even then they're not precisely symmetric.)  Keep that in mind and everything should make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You don't see three branches on git  push. Only two

The `foo2` you are describing is for git pull (git fetch + git merge) or `git rebase`:
(from [`git config`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-config.html))

```
branch.<name>.merge
```

> Defines, together with `branch.<name>.remote`, the upstream branch for the given branch.
>   It tells `git fetch/git pull/git rebase` which branch to merge and can also affect git push (see `push.default`).
>   When in branch `<name>`, it tells git fetch the default refspec to be marked for merging in `FETCH_HEAD`. The value is handled like the remote part of a refspec, and must match a ref which is fetched from the remote given by "`branch.<name>.remote`".
>
> **The merge information is used by `git pull` (which at first calls `git fetch`) to lookup the default branch for merging**.
>   Without this option, `git pull` defaults to merge the first refspec fetched.
>   Specify multiple values to get an octopus merge.

Note that with *after* git1.7.10, the default push policy might change to `matching` to `upstream` (see "[What is the result of `git push origin`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586687/what-is-the-result-of-git-push-origin/9749477#9749477)"), which means, `branch.<name>.merge` defining an *upstream* branch (in the absence of `branch.<name>.remote`), it could then be used by default for a `git push`.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the remote-tracking branch has the same name as the branch on the remote repo. It would be somewhat confusing otherwise !

So, `origin/foo3` simply represents branch `foo3` in the remote `origin`. It will be properly synced with the remote after running `git fetch`. Note that when running `git pull`, you are actually running `git fetch ; git merge`.

When running `git push origin foo1:foo3`, you push your local branch `foo1` to the remote branch `origin/foo3`. So in your case it doesn't make sense to specify a branch `foo2`.

Comment: See, I can do `git checkout -b foo1; git pull origin foo3:remotes/origin/foo2`. So in the pull scenario I have now exactly the 3 branches described in my question. Here it is possibly to specificity each of the 3 branches. All three _can_ have different names, even though it might make no sense. But somehow the other way round, can only affect foo1 and foo3 (`git push origin foo1:foo3`), but no longer foo2, and this totally confuses me; I don't understand that asymmetry. I am sure i miss something.