# Git: Commit stopped by other branch being behind

Tags: git, branch, commit, pull, behind

We've recently adopted our own branch system with Git, but one thing we've been getting frustrated with recently is when trying to commit a change to remote whilst on one branch, Git stops the commit because a different branch is behind its remote counterpart. Therefore, we then have to checkout to each branch that has changed and do a pull first before going back to our original branch to make a commit.

Is there a setting that can prevent Git from stopping commits because of other branches. Is there a certain approach we can take that can prevent the need to have to switch branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

It should avoid the kind of error message [mentioned here](http://jimkubicek.com/blog/2012/08/16/git-push-current-branch/)

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:jkubicek/my_proj.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. If you did not intend to push that branch, you may want to
hint: specify branches to push or set the 'push.default' configuration
hint: variable to 'current' or 'upstream' to push only the current branch
```

Comment: That is the kind of setting, discussed in http://lists-archives.com/git/767304-push-default-current-vs-upstream.html, which lead to new push policy with Git1.7.11+: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586687/what-is-the-result-of-git-push-origin/9749477#9749477