# git "Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged" after fresh clone of remote repo

Tags: git

When I clone a remote repository with

1. `git clone 'repo_url'`
2. `git pull`
3. `git status`

I get this message -

```
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 41 and 20 different commits each, respectively
```

When I use `git pull -a` I do not have this issue.

Are things out of sync on the remote repo? with the HEAD and the master ?
How do I fix it?

**EDIT 1 :**

when I run git branch -a : this is what it looks like...

$ git branch -a

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/clothes
  remotes/origin/dunnesBranch
  remotes/origin/master
```

**EDIT 2 :**

It seems to me that origin/master is not pointing to the latest code...
I ran 'git clone ' then 
`git reset --hard origin/master`
and then a 'git pull' and it attempted a merge which failed due to conflicts...

I think...
The HEAD of the remote repo is pointing to the latest commit, origin/master is pointing to a different, older commit...
I can verify this when I run git show...

Comment: possible duplicate of [master branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, how to 'undiverge' branches'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452226/master-branch-and-origin-master-have-diverged-how-to-undiverge-branches)

Comment: This sounds very strange. After a fresh clone it diverges... is it a public branch by any change that I can clone on to test?

Comment: What are your *exact* steps?

Comment: my steps are exactly that...(1) git clone (2) git pull (3) git status, interestingly if i do 'git pull -a' i dont see the "diverged message"

Comment: @IamReck - Sorry, its not public... I won't be able to share it...

Comment: Can you post the output of a `git branch -a` command?

Comment: Possibly dumb question: did you "cd" into the freshly cloned repo, or are you doing a "git pull" / "git pull -a" in a *different* repo?

Comment: @IamReck - posted it there...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure about the cause, unless:

- there is a [`git push --force`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15030429/6309) on `origin` by someone else, done between you cloning the repo, and you pulling that same repo
- the fetch refspec (`git config --get remote.origin.fetch`) isn't `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.

But you can reset master easily enough:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Make sure [`master` is tracking `origin/master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/6309):

```
git branch -u origin/master master
```

And make sure your [push policy is '`simple`'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9749477/6309) (in order to push the current branch out to the same name at the remote repository, only when it is set to track the branch with the same name over there):

```
 git config --global push.default simple
```

---

Summary of the comments: the root cause seems to be related to the 1.7.x version of git used for those operation. It seems to work fine with a latest git1.8.3.

Comment: ok.. ran git reset --hard origin/master and then did a pull.. and it attempted a merge( which failed).I fixed this manually... now i get the message (origin/master is 42 commits behind) ( after a fresh clone and pull).. it seems to me that origin/master is not being updated? or the head isn't pointing to it, but to somewhere else..?

Comment: @user2283043 yes, I wonder where your local master is pointing to: what is the output of `git config --get-all branch.master`?

Comment: Thanks though - you've helped me get a better understanding of it... although i'm still not there yet.. it seems that when i do a 'git pull' I get different information than 'git clone', because the results of 'git reset --hard origin/master' are different for each one..

Comment: @user2283043 could you at least set first the upstream branch of master as intructed in the answer? `git branch -u origin/master master`? *Then* do a `git reset --hard origin/master` and a `git pull`?

Comment: I can't run `branch -u` (using 1.7x) so i ran `git branch --set-upstream master origin/master` then `git pull` and this message is returned ` + 05407b6...e6cd630 HEAD       -> origin/HEAD  (forced update)` - however - I ran git pull a second time and the output was `e6cd630..05407b6  master     -> origin/master`.

Comment: @user2283043 did you do the `git reset --hard origin/master` before the `git pull`? Any chance you could upgrade your git to a 1.8.3+?

Comment: sorry,Yes. I did those 3 commands in order.. `git branch..` `git reset...` then `git pull`.. I'll update to 1.8.3+ now and try again. thanks.

Comment: ok.. Tried it using Git 1.8.3 and it worked! Seems to be back in sync now.. Thank You!

Comment: @user2283043 Excellent! Must have been some weird error linked to the old version of git. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when the origin history has been altered by means of "amend", "reset" or similar git commands, see [here](http://www.codeovertones.com/2012/10/when-your-git-branch-diverges-from-your.html) for some details

Comment: After a fresh clone and pull though?

Comment: His branch and origin/master have 41 and 20 different commits each, respectively. That ain't normal.