# Executed git merge branch command before git push origin branch

Tags: git, version-control, github

I have dev-master branch & I have created new branch - feature_10 and started working on it for a feature. I have completed my task and then executed below command -

```
git add *.java

git commit -m "comment"

git checkout dev-master

git merge feature_10

git push origin feature_10
```

This commit is visible on repository (web) but I am not able to raise NEW MERGE REQUEST on web as the feature_10 branch is not listing in branch drop-down box.

I have executed wrong command steps, I should have 1st pushed the branch and then should executed merge command.

Now how to correct it ? Please advise ?

Comment: When you executed `git push origin feature_10` did you get output that looked like this: `*[new branch] feature_10 -> feature_10`?

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't merge your feature_branch into `dev_master`.

You should do your merge request (as you intended to) form the remote side, branch feature, and wait for `dev_master` to be updated with it in the *original* repo that you have forked.

Then you can pull from that original repo in order to update your `dev_master`, and push that updated version to your fork (web). And you can delete your feature branch, since it has been accepted and integrated into `dev_master` in the original repo.

---

Regarding the push, check;

- the `git config push.default` policy.
  With recent git, make sure it is [set to '`simple`'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9749477/6309).
- check the branch config upstream branch, to see if it wasn't already set to *antoehr* branch.

  ```
  git config branch.feature_10.merge
  git config branch.feature_10.origin
  ```

Comment: Is it okay to revert or undo the merge ? It's already pushed on remote with same branch name.

Comment: @Santosh if you are pushing to *your* fork, meaning nobody else pull from it, you can reset locally, redo your local history right, and `git push --force`.