# How to fork and a Git repo to my repo

Tags: git, repository, fork

I have started using Git today and loving it.

I have this doubt - could any one please help me out

A repo for eg https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife can be forked by pressing fork on the page. This then appears in my github like this - https://github.com/usrname/Spoon-Knife.git

I have a test git like this https://github.com/usrname/test.git

And I want the Spoon-Knife to appear within 'test' repo like this https://github.com/usrname/test/Spoon-Knife

How to do this - please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but then your https://github.com/usrname/test.git won't be a fork.
Just a regular cloned repo, without any special relationship with the original repo https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife.

- git clone your fork
- make a local branch for any remote branch you have fetch with that clone: see the details in "[Track all remote git branches as local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309)"
- add `test.git` as a remote to your local clone, named '`test`'
- push everything back to test.git

That would be:

```
git clone https://github.com/usrname/Spoon-Knife.git
cd Spoon-Knife
git fetch --tags
remote=origin ; for brname in `git branch -r | grep $remote | grep -v master | grep -v HEAD | awk '{gsub(/[^\/]+\//,"",$1); print $1}'`; do git branch --set-upstream-to $brname  $remote/$brname ; done
git remote add test https://github.com/usrname/test.git
git config push.default matching
git push --all
git push --tags
git config push.default simple
```

For the push policies (the `config push.default` part), see "[What is the result of `git push origin`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9749477/6309)".

Comment: Sorry for getting back late, I tried the above and when git push --all is done or --tags - everything is up-to-date is returned.